# how to retrieve the record from database by using spring 2.0 with hibernate springMVC

Tags: java, spring

Am using SimpleFormController am getting nullpointer Exception can any one please suggest the how can i retrieve record from database and display it in browser....

regards
srikar
thnx

Comment: You need to improve the question: Read this to see how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: please provide additional details and context to your question

Comment: give me a good example for retrieve records from datavase by using Spring2 mvc and hibernate

Comment: Please provide some code support for the question

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what property is giving you the NullPointerException (NPE). If you're using Spring MVC then it's likely that your DAO or Manager is giving you the NPE because it hasn't been initialized before you attempt to use it.

Could you share your the code in your Controller where you declare either your DAO or Manager?

Okay, looking at your code I would imagine you're receiving your NPE at this line:

```
ArrayList list = (ArrayList)edao.findAll();
```

I would begin looking at the EmpJB class and ensure you have all of the dependent properties initialized.

Comment: what code have to write in controller and which methode i have to use

Comment: public class RetrieveController extends SimpleFormController {

 public RetrieveController(){
  System.out.println("we are in construcot");
  setCommandClass(RetrieveController.class);
 }
 
 public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
  EmpJB edao = new EmpJB();
  ArrayList list = (ArrayList)edao.findAll();
  request.setAttribute("emp", list);
  
  System.out.println("we are in handle");
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
  mav.setViewName("rc");
  return mav;
 }

Comment: It'd be better to put it in the question, not as a comment for an answer.